# what is the unit for the Three js objects?

Tags: three.js

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    35,         // Field of view
    800 / 640,  // Aspect ratio
    .1,         // Near
    10000       // Far
);

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.CubeGeometry( 5, 5, 5 ),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } )
);
```

In camera, what is the unit for Near and Far parameters.

In Cube what is the unit of the parameters for CubeGeometry

Please point me to the url where, i can find details about

Object space - (the local axis used to draw an object)
World space - (the global axis)

Answer (score 12):

Pretty sure these parameters are units in OpenGL. If you look at the OpenGL red book, for each in chapter 3

http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html

There's a short paragraph here:

> The preceding paragraph mentions inches and millimeters - do these
>   really have anything to do with OpenGL? The answer is, in a word, no.
>   The projection and other transformations are inherently unitless. If
>   you want to think of the near and far clipping planes as located at
>   1.0 and 20.0 meters, inches, kilometers, or leagues, it's up to you. The only rule is that you have to use a consistent unit of
>   measurement. Then the resulting image is drawn to scale.

So to answer your question, the units are whatever you think they should be, they are a purely relative scale.

Answer (score 7):

The official answer is that ThreeJS uses SI units for all measures, see here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6259